# Tesseract OCR cant recognize simple math symbols

Tags: python, python-tesseract

so basicly im trying to make tesseract ocr do some elementary school math, but it wont work it prints out the math but not the answer to the math, here is my code

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\alloa026\Downloads\project\photo.png'
content = pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\alloa026\Downloads\project\photo.png')
print(eval("content.strip()"))
```

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you note that, you should correct the last line

```
print(eval("content.strip()")
to
print(eval(content.strip())
```